# Publish an application Upgrade on Google Play Store

Tags: cordova, google-play

I have already published a cordova(phonegap) application on Android Market(Google Play Store) and i try right now to upgrade it on market but the version of the application is always the same (1) in Android Manifest.xml whereas i change it to 2 and rebuild the apk with cordova... It's like the application version is hard coded in the AndroidManifest with "1". It is changed every time when i rebuild the application using cordova.

Please is there a patch somewhere or someone to explain me how to change it ?

Thank you by advance.

Answer (score 2):

As you develop your app, you'll want to update it periodically.

In order for the Google Play Store to accept updated APKs, you'll need to midify the platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml file to increment the android:versionCode value.

Credit to : http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html

You can edit the main config.xml at project root level which will automatically update all platforms (in the subdirectories off project root), including Android,  with this new version number.

Comment: thats what i have mentioned, we can do that but after changed the versionCode it will be resetting again if i rebuild the app using cordova

Comment: You need to modify the project level .xml file. You are modifying the android level one  - which get's automatically updated based on the version specificed in the higher (project) level file.

Comment: did you mean that it is config.xml

Comment: yes @barneymc i got it. i have changed higher level androidmanifest.xml not low level manifest.xml. but after rebuilding the app using cordova it is changing the higher level xml file

Comment: How do you build? Cordova build or any other script file?